# How to compare two audio files that maybe have been recorded in the same environment

Tags: wave

I have two audio files that I think they were recorded in the same room. Is there any tool that can be used to compare both of them. Knowing that sample rate and format are the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted a question not long ago that may give you a heuristic.

[Independent Component Analysis (ICA) Real Life Implementation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/47983/independent-component-analysis-ica-real-life-implementation)

ICA seems to have had a problem demixing under the circumstances mentioned.

You could try adding the 2 sound records and seeing if they demix or not.

Without a probabilistic model, I don't see a ready metric that you could use, but you might develop something using trial and error.

Rooms do sound differently under different circumstances.  People, furniture, temperature, .... have effects.